# Monitor FFMPEG Rtmp live stream with FFPLAY pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, rtmp

I have wrestled with this for hours and can not figure out how to pipe this to ffplay so that i can monitor it.

google searches and searches on here and stack overflow come up empty

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -stats -re -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i %list% -auto_convert 1 -c:v libx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -preset veryfast -b:v 1984k -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -tune zerolatency -vf "pp=hb/vb/dr/fq|8,crop=in_w-20:in_h-40,scale=960:540:flags=lanczos,setsar=1,format=yuv420p,eq=gamma=0.95" -g 50 -fflags +genpts -f flv %video% - | ffplay -f flv -x 720 -y 480
```

I have tried doing a standalone  just ffplay but it wont see it

I am sure there must be a way to accomplish this in a easy way, without needing to have webpage open that drains the cpu while trying to stream

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it!

if anyone wants to clean this up let me know, it does work though as is

this is the partial code from the windows batch file:

```
ECHO Type in your stating playlist file
ECHO.
set /p list=""
set video=rtmp://stream.ssh101.com/live/XXXXXXXXX

bin\ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel quiet -stats -re -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i %list% -flags +global_header -auto_convert 1 -c:v libx264 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -preset veryfast -b:v 1984k -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -tune zerolatency -g 50 -fflags +genpts -map 0:v -map 0:a -f tee "[f=flv]%video%|[f=nut]pipe:" | bin\ffplay -hide_banner -loglevel 0 pipe: -window_title "RTMP Stream Monitor 1.0 - Viewer (powered by FFPlay)" -x 640 -y 480  -sync audio -autoexit -exitonmousedown -autorotate
```

Hope this helps someone in the future and definitely look forward to anything to add to this to make it even better